# MySQL Conditional JOIN Using CASE Stmt

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case

I need to modify a stored procedure which needs to join a specific table based on a bool value provided within the CALL.

Is this possible in MySQL. The general syntax below is not working for me:

```
select...
from table_one t1
case 1=1 join table_two on t1.id = t2.id end;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted to do is simply this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one as t1
LEFT JOIN table_two t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id AND 1=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to do something like this:

```
-- dummy procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE get_result(IN id int(11))
  SELECT t1.* FROM table_one t1 
  INNER JOIN table_two t2 ON IF(id = 1, 1, 0) && t2.id = t1.id
```

To have different query executed depending on the parameter sent to the procedure you could also do:

```
-- dummy procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE get_result(IN id int(11))
  BEGIN
    CASE id 
    -- if supplied argument is equal to '1' select all fields from table_one
    WHEN 1 THEN SELECT * FROM table_one;
    -- else select all fields from table_one & table_two
    ELSE SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table_one t1 INNER JOIN table_two t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    END CASE;
  END;
```